# Trying to update column values by submit button

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to update `status` on my leaves table by pressing the approve/reject button. Here's my table schema:

[image: Table Schema]

So far this is what i've done:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['approved']))
    {
        echo "Approved";
        $status=$_POST['approved'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['rejected']))
    {
        echo "Rejected";
        $status=$_POST['rejected'];
    }
?>

    <!-- Begin page content -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h3>Employee Leaves</h3>
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Employee Name</th>
                        <th>Phone</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>From</th>
                        <th>To</th>
                        <th>Reason</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>---</th>
                    </tr>
                <?php
                    include ('database.php');
                    $result = $database->prepare ("SELECT * FROM leaves order by id DESC");
                    $result ->execute();
                    for ($count=0; $row_message = $result ->fetch(); $count++){
                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $row_message['full_name']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row_message['phone']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row_message['email']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row_message['fromdate']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row_message['todate']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row_message['reason']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row_message['status']; ?></td>
                        <td>
                            <form method="post" action="update.php">
                                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row_message['id']; ?>" />
                                <input type="submit" value="Approved" name="approved"></input>
                               <input type="submit" value="Rejected" name="rejected"></input>
                            </form>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php   }   ?>

                    </table>

                    <a href="home"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></i> Back</button></a>   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

and here's my update.php

```
<?php

    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    mysqli_select_db($con, 'leaves');

    $sql = "UPDATE leaves SET status = :status WHERE id = :id";

    if(mysqli_query($con, $sql))
        header("refresh:1; url=view-leave.php");
    else
        echo "Error";
?>
```

I'm getting the "error" when I click on approve/reject. I think the problem is with the `update.php`. I'm not sure what it is tho or where.

Comment: @NanThiyagan I'm getting the word "error". The one I put on my update.php

Comment: I think you can use  mysql affected rows function for check update result see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php. explain more about error message , please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this : `update.php`

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['approved']))
    {
        $msg = "Approved";
        $status=$_POST['approved'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['rejected']))
    {
        $msg = "Rejected";
        $status=$_POST['rejected'];
    }
    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    mysqli_select_db($con, 'leaves');

    $sql = "UPDATE newusers SET username = '$status' WHERE id = '$id'";

    if(mysqli_query($con, $sql))
        header("refresh:1; url=index.php?msg=$msg");
    else
        var_dump(mysqli_error($con));
    ?>
```

and `view-leave.php`

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['msg']))
    {
        echo $_GET['msg'];
    }
?>

    <!-- Begin page content -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h3>Employee Leaves</h3>
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Employee Name</th>
                        <th>Phone</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>From</th>
                        <th>To</th>
                        <th>Reason</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>---</th>
                    </tr>
                <?php
                    include ('database.php');
                    $result = $database->prepare ("SELECT * FROM leaves order by id DESC");
                    $result ->execute();
                    for ($count=0; $row_message = $result ->fetch(); $count++){
                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $row_message['full_name']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row_message['phone']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row_message['email']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row_message['fromdate']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row_message['todate']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row_message['reason']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row_message['status']; ?></td>
                        <td>
                            <form method="post" action="update.php">
                                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row_message['id']; ?>" />
                                <input type="submit" value="Approved" name="approved"></input>
                               <input type="submit" value="Rejected" name="rejected"></input>
                            </form>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php   }   ?>

                    </table>

                    <a href="home"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></i> Back</button></a>   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm I tried it but I still get the "error". Thanks tho.

Comment: add `die(mysqli_error($con));`  before `echo "Error";` and get the error message.

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':status WHERE id = :row_id' at line 1` Mhmmm

Comment: @John Check my answer. You need to replace `:status` and `:id` with `$status` and  `$id`.

Comment: I did use your answer and changed `:status` and `:id` with `$status` and `$id` but I still get "error"

Comment: I just get the word "error" nothing else. I also tried putting `die(mysqli_error($con))` before `echo "Error";` and I woudl get `unexpected error, unexpected echo`

Comment: @JonhZ I've updated the answer please check updated answer now. I've also tested it in my local environment.

Comment: Oh my god thank you so much, I've been wanting to do this for a long time now! You're a life saver!

Comment: Welcome! Try to debug your code and you won't need help from anyone for such small issues.

Comment: I'll hold onto that :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to write database name here:

```
mysqli_select_db($con, 'dbname');
```

Comment: Oh my god I didn't realize that lol, thanks for pointing it out. I still get the "error" tho.

Comment: try to do like this        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  echo   'your code';
} else {
  echo  'error';
}

Comment: Still the same, sorry.

Comment: update.php <?php
    if(isset($_POST['approved']))
    {
        $msg = "Approved";
        $status=$_POST['approved'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['rejected']))
    {
        $msg = "Rejected";
        $status=$_POST['rejected'];
    }
    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    mysqli_select_db($con, 'leaves');

    $sql = "UPDATE leaves SET status = .'$status'. WHERE id = .'$id'.";

    if(mysqli_query($con, $sql))
        header("refresh:1; url=view-leave.php?msg=$msg");
    else
        echo "Error";
?>

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to declare a default value for the `$msg='';` and `$status = '';`?